# How many (or percentage) satellites of Solar system planets have their orbits synchronized like the Moon (always facing earth)?

Tags: satellite

Mercury and Venus have no satellites. Then earth has moon (synchronized orbit). For Mars - both its satellites (Fobos and Deimos) also synchronized. Analyzing other planets is hard - too many satellites. Maybe someone knows percentage - all of them synchronized or which ones are not synchronized (if just a few ones are not synchronized). All 4 largest Jupiter satellites are also synchronized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not really known; while the rotation period of most of the larger satellites is known, and they're mostly synchronized, for the smaller ones it's harder to determine and they're [less likely to be synchronized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_locking#Timescale):

> One conclusion is that, other things being equal ... a large moon will lock faster than a smaller moon at the same orbital distance from the planet. ... A possible example of this is in the Saturn system, where Hyperion is not tidally locked, whereas the larger Iapetus, which orbits at a greater distance, is.

Wikipedia has a [list of synchronized satellites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_locking#List_of_known_tidally_locked_bodies) and 'suspects', if you want to investigate further.